I setup Firebase console for App Distribution with company account. The console is not accessable- getting 401
Error screenshotI want to set up a Firebase console for App  Distribution without a Gmail account(company account). I followed the instructions and was done with the setup but the console UI is not accessible from the organization network- getting 401. But I can able to access it from my personal network. Attaching the error screenshot.
I tried to create a Firebase Console for App Distribution.
